# DateTime? in an EF model doesn't seem to be nullable when I call .ToList to convert it to a string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I have a controller returning all the columns in my model. However when i  change the model so my a field with a Date is of the DateTime type i get the following error.

> "The 'StartDate' property on 'Battle' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.

All I did was change the StartDate property to have DateTime? instead of a String in front of it and it broke. If i change it back to string it works well.

Heres my model

```
  public class Battle
  {

    [Key]
    public int BattleID{ get; set; }
    public string General { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Heres my controller method

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllBattles()
    {
        using (BattleContext db = new BattleContext())
        {
            var query = (from results in db.Battle
                         select results);

            List<Battle> output = new List<Battle>();
            output = query.ToList();
            return Ok(output);
        }

    }
```

Mind you this worked fine before I changed StartDate from string to a nullable DateTime. (I would like it to be a DateTime so i can easily find battles within 50 or 100 years in other methods).

Comment: Is it a DateTime2 value in the database? If it isn't you may need to convert it to a DateTime is MS SQL before assigning it to the model.

Comment: If the DB schema says `NOT NULL`, then using a nullable in C# won't make any difference.

Comment: @ChadMcGrath that was the problem thanks didnt realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error i was making was very silly here. I accidentally had that column declared as a string in my SQL database rather than a datetime. Fixing it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the only difference I have in my code (Which allows null values for my dates) is this qualifying statement in my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
```

so maybe give that a try?  If that doesn't work comment below and I can check some other parts of my project.

Comment: The data annotations didnt alter it because my database wasnt generated via the code first method. Altering this wouldnt solve the issue, the issue was the type in the SQL Db being a string.